# What's the name of that Apple tool which will apply the rounded corners and gloss effect to your icon graphics?

Tags: iphone, icons

I need to preview my iphone app icons and also need to export these for the web. I remember Apple had a tool that would take a file, apply those effects and then save it. What's the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are not talking about this app, but I think it could be useful:

[iPhone Icon Composer 1.0](http://web.me.com/ryanmoniz/My_Applications/Cocoa_Applications/Entries/2009/3/1_iPhone_Icon_Composer_1.0.html)